# Maximum size of object macro

Tags: c, macros, stdint

I tried to write the following:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *ptr = malloc(SIZE_MAX);
```

But the compiler gave me the following warning:

```
warning: argument 1 value ‘18446744073709551615’ exceeds maximum object 
size 9223372036854775807 [-Walloc-size-larger-than=]
```

That sounds reasonable. But anyway I'd like to allocate an object of the max possible size on the current implementation/arch. There is the macro `RSIZE_MAX` defined in the `Annex.B(19)`:

```
__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__
RSIZE_MAX
```

So I tried the following [example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a585c9a931791a4):

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    void *ptr = malloc(RSIZE_MAX);
}
```

But with no effect, the `RSIZE_MAX` is not defined. How to use this macro or any other way to verify maximum object size at compile time?

Comment: `SIZE_MAX` refers to the maximum value that can be contained in a `size_t` variable.

Comment: @MrPromethee Yes, but how about the warning. What is the macro to get the limit `9223372036854775807`?

Comment: @MrPromethee But the argument to [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) *is* a `size_t`, so that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSIZE_MAX` is defined in C11 Annex K, which is optional. An implementation that supports it will predefine the macro `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`.  The gcc/glibc implementation I use on my Ubuntu system, for example, does not support it, and therefore does not define `RSIZE_MAX`.

In any case, there's no guarantee that `malloc(RSIZE_MAX)` will succeed, nor is there any implication in the standard that `RSIZE_MAX`, even if it's defined, is the maximum allocation size supported by `malloc`. Evaluating `malloc(RSIZE_MAX+1)` isn't even a *runtime-constraint violation*; `malloc()` still takes an argument of type `size_t`, not `rsize_t`. `malloc` reports failure by returning a null pointer.

See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) K.3.4:

> The macro is
>
> **`RSIZE_MAX`**
>
> which expands to a value of type **`size_t`**. Functions that have
>   parameters of type
>   **`rsize_t`** consider it a runtime-constraint violation if the values of those parameters are greater than **`RSIZE_MAX`**.

Note that on some systems (particularly Linux-based systems), `malloc()` can appear to succeed, returning a non-null result, even if there isn't enough memory available for the allocation. See "overcommit" and "OOM killer".

Answer (score 3):

The define `SIZE_MAX` defines the maximum value of the data type `size_t`. The data type `size_t` is capable to store the size of any object. The maximum size depends on the bus with like 32 or 64 bit.

If you try to allocated memory of the the maximum countable size of memory, it must fail, since this would block your entire address space. The compiler gives you a warning that the `malloc` call will always fail. The requested size just makes no sense.

BTW: 9223372036854775807 is 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Comment: Yes, but where did the limit `9223372036854775807` come from?

Comment: @St.Antario That seems to be a compiler-specific limit.

Comment: 9223372036854775807 is 2^63 - 1